# Ruby: combine Date and Time objects into a DateTime

Tags: ruby

Simple question, but I can't find a good or definitive answer.  What is the best and most efficient way to combine Ruby Date and Time objects (**objects**, not strings) into a single DateTime object?

Answer (score 59):

I found this, but it's not as elegant you would hope:

```
d = Date.new(2012, 8, 29)
t = Time.now
dt = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, t.zone)
```

By the way, the ruby Time object also stores a year, month, and day, so you would be throwing that away when you create the DateTime.

Comment: It's not elegant for sure, but how about putting that into some kind of utility class and use it from there, like this: `Utils.datetime_from_date_and_time(date, time)` or something shorter. Your utility method will contain a non-elegant code, but the users of the code will simply have a handy and readable tool at their hands.

Comment: This answer caused me a lot of trouble with daylight savings time. The resulting DateTime object will be in the current time zone rather than the time zone it should be in based on the date. If you are saving it to a database in UTC (as you should), when you try to get it back it could be an hour off. See @Alexander Clarke's answer below.

Comment: @JasonGaluten - just parse the time with UTC: Time.find_zone("UTC").parse(START_TIME)

Answer (score 34):

When using `seconds_since_midnight`, changes in daylight savings time can lead to unexpected results.

```rb
Time.zone = 'America/Chicago'
t  = Time.zone.parse('07:00').seconds_since_midnight.seconds
d1 = Time.zone.parse('2016-11-06').to_date # Fall back
d2 = Time.zone.parse('2016-11-07').to_date # Normal day
d3 = Time.zone.parse('2017-03-12').to_date # Spring forward

d1 + t
#=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 06:00:00 CST -06:00
d2 + t
#=> Mon, 07 Nov 2016 07:00:00 CST -06:00
d3 + t
#=> Sun, 12 Mar 2017 08:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

Here's an alternative, similar to @selva-raj's answer above, using string interpolation, `strftime`, and `parse`. `%F` is equal to `%Y-%m-%d` and `%T` is equal to `%H:%M:%S`.

```rb
Time.zone = 'America/Chicago'
t = Time.zone.parse('07:00')
d1 = Time.zone.parse('2016-11-06').to_date # Fall back
d2 = Time.zone.parse('2016-11-07').to_date # Normal day
d3 = Time.zone.parse('2017-03-12').to_date # Spring forward

Time.zone.parse("#{d1.strftime('%F')} #{t.strftime('%T')}")
#=> Sun, 06 Nov 2016 07:00:00 CST -06:00
Time.zone.parse("#{d2.strftime('%F')} #{t.strftime('%T')}")
#=> Sun, 07 Nov 2016 07:00:00 CST -06:00
Time.zone.parse("#{d3.strftime('%F')} #{t.strftime('%T')}")
#=> Sun, 12 Mar 2017 07:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

Comment: This is a very underrated answer. If the date you're combining is during daylight savings time and the current time is not (or vice-versa), the resulting time will be off by an hour unless you use one of the methods in this answer.

Comment: Spent hours trying to resolve a date time issue where things were off by an hour since we just had a time change. After reading this answer, I just made a method using your solution, and it totally fixed the issue I've been battling. Great response, and it's still useful in 2020!

Comment: It works for me `Time.zone.parse("#{d1.strftime('%F')} #{t.strftime('%T')}")` . Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Simple:

```
Date.new(2015, 2, 10).to_datetime + Time.parse("16:30").seconds_since_midnight.seconds

# => Object: Tue, 10 Feb 2015 16:30:00 +0000
```

You gotta love Ruby!

Comment: If you want to keep time zone you could do `Date.new(2015, 2, 10).to_time + Time.parse("16:30").seconds_since_midnight.seconds`

Comment: `seconds_since_midnight` can lead to unexpected results when working with time zones and daylight savings. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

If using Rails, try any of these:

```
d = Date.new(2014, 3, 1) 
t = Time.parse("16:30")

dt = d + t.seconds_since_midnight.seconds   
# => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

dt = (d + t.seconds_since_midnight.seconds).to_datetime   
# => DateTime

dt = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec)   
# => DateTime
```

Comment: `dt = d + t.seconds_since_midnight.seconds   ` did the trick for a problem I was having.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, this works great.

I built a method to extend the DateTime class to combine a date and a time. **It takes the zone from the date so that it does not end up an hour off with daylight savings time**.

Also, for convenience, I like being able to pass in strings as well.

```
class DateTime
  def self.combine(d, t)
    # pass in a date and time or strings
    d = Date.parse(d) if d.is_a? String 
    t = Time.zone.parse(t) if t.is_a? String
    # + 12 hours to make sure we are in the right zone
    # (eg. PST and PDT switch at 2am)
    zone = (Time.zone.parse(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + 12.hours ).zone
    new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, zone)
  end
end
```

So you can do:

```
DateTime.combine(3.weeks.ago, "9am")
```

or

```
DateTime.combine("2015-3-26", Time.current)
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, I hope this is correct.

```
 datetojoin=Time.parse(datetime).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       timetojoin=Time.parse(time).strftime("%T")          
       joined_datetime = Time.parse(datetojoin +" "+ timetojoin).strftime("%F %T")
```

Any thoughts?  Please share.