# Combining an ActiveRecord Date and Time into a DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 columns in a table in my database, 1 is a Date and 1 is a Time. I need to use ActiveRecord to combine those into a DateTime object. What's the best way?

```
1.9.3-p194 :053 > date.class
 => Date 
1.9.3-p194 :054 > time.class
 => Time 
1.9.3-p194 :055 > date.to_time_in_current_zone
 => Wed, 04 Sep 2013 00:00:00 PDT -07:00 
1.9.3-p194 :056 > date.to_time_in_current_zone + time
TypeError: not an integer
```

I can add the individual fields of the time and this seems to work:

```
1.9.3-p194 :062 > date.to_time_in_current_zone + time.hour.hours + time.min.minutes + time.sec.seconds
 => Wed, 04 Sep 2013 12:30:00 PDT -07:00
```

That doesn't include milliseconds, does `Time` not have milliseconds? Not the end of the world if I can't have milliseconds, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181444/ruby-combine-date-and-time-objects-into-a-datetime

Comment: @Luke - similar, though my question is about Rails' `Date` and `Time`. I would've imagined that Rails would have a mechanism to support this if Ruby did not.

Comment: A quick perusal of the Rails docs seems to suggest that it does not (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html).

Comment: The link from @Luke is exactly what came to mind for me. It's pretty straight forward that way.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to peep in middle actually i am bit new in rail around 8 months, Its like a small person talking in between big people.
I also was facing this same issue, i got ride from this by using

```
date_time= (date.to_s + " " +time.to_s).to_datetime
```

I dont known if its right or wrong but my problem was solved.
Plz do give me feedback about this :)

Additionally, `Time` has milliseconds which can be accessed through [`#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#strftime-method) with the `%L` format directive. Also, smaller fractional portions of seconds can be accessed by use of `%N`.

Comment: Mr. Questioner If my answer is right Or wrong whatever it be jst give me the feedback about it :P

Comment: `date.to_s + " " +time.to_s` can give you something as weird as `2020-04-05 2000-01-01 09:30:00 UTC`, just in case. I would not go down this road exactly how it is told here

Answer (score 2):

```
merged_datetime = DateTime.new(date_to_merge.year, date_to_merge.month,
                               date_to_merge.day, time_to_merge.hour,
                               time_to_merge.min, time_to_merge.sec)
```